# Extract data from data set based on metadata in second data set

Tags: r, subset

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to extract columns from a data set based on metadata stored in a second data set?  Just wondering if there is a relatively straightforward way (e.g. using "colnames" or "subset"). My original data set is quite large with more than 100 columns and more than 30,000 rows. Opening the file and selecting in Excel is a pain.

Here two example data sets:

```
set1 <- data.frame(ID = rnorm(5, 5000, 1000), Sample1 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500), 
Sample2 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500), Sample3 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500), 
Sample4 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500), Sample5 = rnorm(5, 50000, 2500))

meta.data <- data.frame(Sample_name = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", 
"Sample4", "Sample5"), Location = c("Loc1", "Loc2", "Loc3", "Loc1", "Loc1"), 
Time = c("M0", "M01", "M02", "M02", "M03"), 
Conc = c("lo", "hi", "lo", "lo", "lo"))
```

(1) How could I extract (as a new data set) all samples from Location Loc1 or all samples from Time M02?

(2) How could I extract a row that has a certain ID number and select only those samples within that row that have a Conc "lo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, with a merge possibly being more appropriate, but here is how to do some subsetting:

(1) How could I extract (as a new data set) all samples from Location Loc1...

```
#get a list of the samples all from Location Loc1
as.character(meta.data$Sample_name[meta.data$Location=="Loc1"])
#use this list of samples to subset the set1 data
set1[c("ID",as.character(meta.data$Sample_name[meta.data$Location=="Loc1"]))]

        ID  Sample1  Sample4  Sample5
1 3836.499 53304.29 47720.79 49504.96
2 4620.443 49406.93 49123.49 50419.93
3 5614.903 44413.93 50387.27 48652.29
4 6676.880 52732.63 48282.92 53544.17
5 3926.077 52593.59 50204.96 49563.13
```

(2) How could I extract a row that has a certain ID number and select only those samples within that row that have a Conc "lo"?

I've just used `set1$ID[1]` as a replacement for a selected `ID` here due to the example being random numbers. Just replace it with something like `set1$ID=="idnum1"`

```
subset(set1,set1$ID==set1$ID[1])[c("ID",as.character(meta.data$Sample_name[meta.data$Conc=="lo"]))]

        ID  Sample1  Sample3  Sample4  Sample5
1 3836.499 53304.29 49706.58 47720.79 49504.96
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  Have yet to try it with the real data set but I could replicate your method with another dummy data set. However, set1$ID=="idnum1" did not work (when replacing idnum1 with a number occurring the ID column). set1$ID[X] works (X being a row number)

Comment: Beware that the data in your example data.frame has floating point numbers so that an id that displays in R as `3836.499` is actually `3836.49897995278` . If your real ID's are text or a number without decimals the code should work just fine.

Comment: @thelatemail: those are the known R gotchas for decimals and similarly, precision on seconds,: *`options('digits'=n)`* *`options('digits.secs'=n)`* ; [both those FAQs come up very often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494188/zoo-objects-and-millisecond-timestamps).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach that involves turning `set1`into long data format and then joining it to `meta.data`:

```
library(reshape2)
set1.m <- melt(set1)
merge(set1.m, meta.data, by.x = "variable", by.y = "Sample_name", all = TRUE)
#-----
   variable     value Location Time Conc
1        ID  4168.153     <NA> <NA> <NA>
2        ID  5402.048     <NA> <NA> <NA>
..
..
29  Sample5 49668.695     Loc1  M03   lo
30  Sample5 52869.040     Loc1  M03   lo
```

I wasn't sure whether the ID column should have been melted or not. You can simply change the `melt` call to `set1.m <- melt(set1, id.vars = "ID")` if not.

Regardless, the data in this format can be subsetted using `subset()` or the `[` operator directly now.

Comment: Thanks!  This is also an interesting approach.  Not sure how well it will work with the original data set b/c the melted data set would be very long (150 samples x 55,000 rows).  But if it works I guess I could use "cast" to rearrange and select data points (if I knew how to use "cast")